# Create a new column and assign value for each group starting using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column as 'fold' and assign new values to it depending on group of quote_id.Let's say if 3 quote_id is same then it should assign 1 and next 4 quote_id is same then it should assign 2.

In short it should assign a number to a particular group of quote_id. 
I have been trying from long time but I am not getting expected results.

```
i=1 def func(x): x['fold']=i return x in_df.groupby('quote_id').apply(func) i=i+1
```

My output should look like below.

```
quote_id    fold
1300079-DE  1
1300079-DE  1
1300079-DE  1
1300185-DE  2
1300560-DE  3
1301011-DE  4
1301011-DE  4
1301011-DE  4
1301644-DE  5
1301907-DE  6
1301907-DE  6
1301907-DE  6
```

Comment: Please post your code not just the output you want.

Comment: i=1
def func(x):
    x['fold']=i
    return x    

    in_df.groupby('quote_id').apply(func)
i=i+1
this is my code. it creates 2 for every group in 'fold' column. and when i export my file fold in not created in csv file. i doubt if my code in correct. Let me know if you need further information

Comment: Please post your code in the question not in the comment.

Comment: @Joe R i have posted my code in question. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) with `method='dense'`:

```
In [10]:
df['fold'] = df['quote_id'].rank(method='dense')
df

Out[10]:
      quote_id  fold
0   1300079-DE     1
1   1300079-DE     1
2   1300079-DE     1
3   1300185-DE     2
4   1300560-DE     3
5   1301011-DE     4
6   1301011-DE     4
7   1301011-DE     4
8   1301644-DE     5
9   1301907-DE     6
10  1301907-DE     6
11  1301907-DE     6
```

Comment: thanks EdChum this is what i wanted. thanks again you solved my problem